# RapidSVN Error: Error while updating filelist (Unknown error! )

Tags: rapidsvn

I have been using RapidSVN for quite sometime now. When i was updating some of the directories my ubuntu system hanged and i had to restart the rapidSVN after it was back to normal. Since then i'm not been able to access the directories through RapidSVN. Observing **Error: Error while updating filelist (Unknown error!)**. What should i do now to make it work again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved.

First i tried cleanup through command-line and after about 20 minutes i had to abort it since it was taking too much time. Then i was able to see files in RapidSVN and i tried update but it showed me error saying try cleanup. Then i ran cleanup through RapidSVN and it was again taking too much time and i switched off my wifi and cleanup was complete.

Now rapidSVN is again working. :D